# Cassandra read latencies

Tags: cassandra, metrics, latency

What is the difference between these read latency metrics?

```
org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ClientRequest.Read.Latency
org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily.system.batchlog.ReadLatency
org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily.system.batchlog.CoordinatorReadLatency
org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily.system.batchlog.CoordinatorScanLatency
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ClientRequest latency is as coordinator, possibly including network latencies between the cluster nodes. The ColumnFamily metrics are local only so its the time to write to memtable/commitlog or pull the data from the sstables.

Comment: does batchlog have to do with logged batches?

Comment: thats the internal system table that batches use, that specific metric is looking at the local latencies for internal processing of batches. ClientRequest.Write.Latency mbean is probably what you want to look at for batchlog monitoring